# Passing a 2d Array to function and returning the 2d array when work is done

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

i am trying to pass a 2d array which contains a Maze to a function, which shall fill it with data received via xbee and returning the new array back to my main.
However I get an Error:

../src/receiveMaze.c:132:13: error: assignment to expression with array type

My Code is:

```
int fillMaze(int maze[10][10]) {

    while (x != 'x') {

        for (row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            for (column = 0; column < 10; column++) {
                maze[row][column] = 1;
            }
        }
        row = 0;
        column = 0;
        while (row != 9 && column != 9) {
            // if the receive buffer is not empty ->
            if (xBee_receivedData()) {
                // -> get next received data byte of the buffer
                x = xBee_readByte();
                a = (int) x + 0;

                if (a == 1) {
                    if (row == 9) {
                        row = 0;
                        column++;
                    } else {
                        row++;
                    }
                } else {
                    maze[row][column] = 0;
                    if (row == 9) {
                        row = 0;
                        column++;
                    } else {
                        row++;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                printf("Error, did not receive data");
            }

            // Delay for the operation loop

        }
    }

    return maze[10][10];
}
```

And i am calling the function in my Main.

```
int main() {

    // initialize the robot
    bot_init();



    // initialize spi-port
    spi_init();

    // initialize the display and the graphical operations
    display_init();
    gfx_init();

    xBee_init();
    int filledMaze[10][10];
    filledMaze = fillMaze(filledMaze);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems:

- `return maze[10][10]` will not return your matrix, it will return a single `int` value that is taken from out-of-bounds indexing of your arrays
- `int fillMaze(int maze[10][10])` says that the function returns a single `int` value, not a matrix (array of arrays)
- `filledMaze = fillMaze(filledMaze)` is wrong first because `fillMaze`is declared to return a single `int` value
- `filledMaze = fillMaze(filledMaze)` is *also* wrong because `filledMaze` is an array, and you can't assign to an array only copy to it

To solve your problem of "returning the 2d array", you first should realize that in this case it's not needed, as the `fillMaze` function already fills the "2d array" you pass as argument. So the solution is simply to not return anything at all:

```
// Fill in the passed "2d" array in-place, don't return anything
void fillMaze(int maze[10][10]) { ... }

// ...

fillMaze(filledMaze);
```

Comment: Ok I got most of it I guess, but your first point is not simple to understand for me. What do i have to write into the function as a parameter? I thought i am just declaring there that the function needs an 10*10 array.

Comment: @Halunke The first point is about the return statement. It will get the *eleventh* element of the *eleventh* array to return. In an array that contains *ten* arrays of *ten* elements.

Comment: @Halunke Ah, it's not about the argument, but the return type. You state in your question that you want to return a "2d" array, but you declare that the function should return a single `int` value.

Comment: Now I get it, thanks very much. Guess it works now (could not really try yet, since my XBee communication seems to be messed up).